# Inputenc/Fontenc conflict

Tags: babel, font-encodings

I am freaking out with this problem.

I am writting a beamer presentation in spanish, and compiling with PDFLaTeX.
My input encoding has to be UTF-8.
So I write:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Test}
    Mínimo: $\min$
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Since I need that characters `<>|` properly see in the output,
I need to use T1 font encoding. So I changed the font to "times".

All that seems going well, but now it emerges the problem that accented commands appear wrong. For example, the command `\min` has to appear as `mín` (with the accented "i"), since in spanish we say "mínimo".
However, the output is: "m/in" or something like that.

I need the correct output, of course: `mín`

Is there a way to ensure that, for all internatl definitions in babel package, accents be produced always "as if" the command `\'` were used?

Comment: Does it  help if you issue `\unaccentedoperators` after loading `babel`?

Comment: @ArashEsbati: I would need the accented version, because the beamer presentation is in even spanish. Anyway, your advice was good enough. At least weird characters are not appearing now. Thank you.

Comment: `times` is obsolete. You should use `mathptmx` or `newtx`. Note `fourier` also  uses T1 encoding for `\mathrm` or `\mathbf`.

Comment: Add `professionalfont` to your options :-)

Comment: I tried lmodern, mathptmx, newtx, and the problem is still there. I think the incompatibility is in beamer, since with "article" everything goes fine.

Comment: @pablo1977 The font set up for `beamer` is 'unusual'. The next release will auto-switch to professional fonts when `lmodern` is loaded.

Comment: Thank you joseph. Maybe Gonzalo has "stoled" your answer. :) Thank you both, then.

Comment: @pablo1977 - Sorry, I got you wrong.  Try a font with sans-serif math, e.g. `\usepackage[math]{MyriadPro}` (if you have it installed, of course).  Or `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` for times.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @ArashEsbati. **newtxmath** did the job perfectly (mathptmx goes fine, but \jmath and \coprod are not working).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid undesired inner replacements, load the `professionalfonts` font theme:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Test}
    Mínimo: $\min$
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

By the way, as **Bernard** mentioned in [`his comment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255199/inputenc-fontenc-conflict/255201#comment610443_255199), instead of `times` you should use a better font package, such as `mathptmx` or `newtx`.

Comment: @pablo1977 You're welcome!